# Differentiation of a Second order Diffferential with Power

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to find the differential of the second-order term with the power (n-1) in the equation below. What differential rule needs to be applied? I can't seem to find a way about it.

\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{d}{d\eta} \left(\left(\frac{d^2 f}{d\eta^2}^\left(n-1\right) \right)\frac{d^2 f}{d\eta^2}\right)
\end{array}

Comment: What is $f^{(n-1)}$ in the first factor? Standard reading would see it as the order $n-1$ derivative of $f$. Does $f$ have only the variable $η$ or is there more structure? In the first case, you get $f^{(n+2)}f''+f^{(n+1)}f'''$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the chain and product rules. Applying the leftmost derivative, you get $[\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}] \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}} + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1} [\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}] = (n-1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-2}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3})(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2}) + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) = (n - 1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) = [(n - 1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1} + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}]\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3} $.

Comment: Hello Amy Ngo, Following what you did, this is what I got.
$[\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}] \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}} + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1} [\frac{d}{dx} \frac{d^{2}f}{dx^{2}}] = (n-1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-2}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3})(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2}) + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) = (n - 1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}(\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3}) = [(n - 1)(\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1} + (\frac{d^{2}f}{dx^2})^{n-1}]\frac{d^{3}f}{dx^3} $.

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. I'd made a mistake with the power on the inner differential.